# Finding the length between two points in 3 Dimensions with Pythagorean's Theorem

Tags: vectors, 3d

I am a grade 11 student and I have to learn vectors for the IB exam. I know that to find the distance of a vector between two points in a 3 dimensional space for lets say point A and B, then you would use the formula 
\begin{align*}
|AB|=\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2+(z_1-z_2)^2}.
\end{align*}
I am having difficulty visualizing and understanding why the coordinates of the points are being subtracted here. I really appreciate the feedback.
Sorry for the low quality of the link, but I guess I don't have enough reputation yet to insert images directly. Also, in the formula all the subscripts should be reversed. So x1 becomes x2 and vice versa.

Comment: If you draw a vector from point $2$ to point $1$, then the differences are just the components of this vector. Hence the given length is the length of the vector.

Comment: Since you square, it does not matter whether you have $x_1-x_2$ or $x_2-x_1$ (same for the other differences)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you know why the distance between $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ is $\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2}$

Refer to the picture below
[image]

Clearly, the vecctor representing $\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2}$ lies in the $XY$ plane.

$z_2-z_1$ lies on the $Z$ axis.

The normal vector to the $XY$ plane is $(0,0,k)$, indicating that the vector representing $\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2}$ and $z_2-z_1$ are perpendicular.

Now, you have two vectors i.e  $\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2}$ and $z_2-z_1$ which are mutually perpendicular and hence you can apply the Pythagorean's Theorem here.

This gives distance between $(x_1, y_1, z_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2, z_2)$ =  $\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2+(z_1-z_1)^2}$